# Cannot change color of SVG Image?

Tags: svg, colors

I cannot change the color of this SVG Image: http://uxrepo.com/download/pause-by-iconic/000000

Here's the SVG's code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" height="1000" width="705">
    <path d="M18 946.5l0 -893l223 0l0 893l-223 0zm446 0l0 -893l224 0l0 893l-224 0z" fill="#000000"/>
</svg>
```

I want the color to be white using the following but it doesn't change anything:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" height="1000" width="705">
    <path d="M18 946.5l0 -893l223 0l0 893l-223 0zm446 0l0 -893l224 0l0 893l-224 0z" fill="#FFFFFFFF"/>
</svg>
```

What's the problem?

I am editing the SVG's code using this site: https://petercollingridge.appspot.com/svg-editor/

Comment: Hex color values must me either three or six hex characters.  Eight is an invalid number of digits.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Colors are RGB hex values, two hex values per component for a 0-255 range means you need 6Fs (2 x R, 2 x G and 2 x B) rather than 8Fs.

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" height="1000" width="705" style="background-color:blue"><path d="M18 946.5l0 -893l223 0l0 893l-223 0zm446 0l0 -893l224 0l0 893l-224 0z" fill="#FFFFFF"/></svg>
```

Answer (score 0):

The 8 char color hex format is not working. Try the standard 6 char hex format like `#00FF00` which works for me.